# SSIS package error, can't find pre-compiled script

Tags: sql-server, ssis, visual-studio

I'm working with an SSIS package (Visual Studio and BIDS/SQL Server 2005 SP3) and out of the blue my script tasks have started failing to compile.

The actual error message: *Validation error.  Generate Inbound Stats Report : The task is configured to pre-compile the script, but binary code is not found. Please visit the IDE in Script Task Editor by clicking Design Script button to cause binary code to be generated.*

**To produce the error, I do the following steps:**

- Edit the existing package in VS
- Open a script task
- On the script tab and click Design Script
- At this point I can just click on the X to close the script, doesn't matter if I save or not
- Click OK on the script task editor window
- Now I have a red X on the task and the error message above

**Other facts:**

- I'm certain this is a local issue and not a problem with the SSIS package because if I break a package, save it, then have another member of my team perform the same steps, the error is fixed.
- ..but I can edit any other package's script tasks without issue (at least as many as I've tried)

This particular package has 4 script tasks, and I can produce the issue by repeating the same steps on 3 of the 4

**Steps I've tried without success**

- Ran a Repair Installation on both SQL Server client tools and Visual Studio
- Completely reinstalled both SQL server client tools (and updated to SP3) and Visual Studio 2005
- A bunch of random workarounds, such as deleting the last line of the script, saving, then replacing it, creating a new script task and deleting the old one.

I haven't yet tried rebuilding the entire package - that would take me all day. Hopefully someone can help me find a better solution than that. The best I've found so far is reinstall and obviously that didn't work for me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Look at your Output/Error window. Why it can't find the compiled script is unknown but if the source got modified and it no longer compiles, you'll get the above situation.

Comment: If you open the script and then choose build does it give you any errors?